# How to restrict the input field to accept only date related inputs in angular8

Tags: angular, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Hi i am using angular8 + jquery for datetimepicker. Here i need to restrict the date input field for date format and even without allowing alphabets except am/pm. so i want the input field to allow either MM/dd/yyyy or m/d/yyyy or mmddyyyy or mmddyyyy hh:mm am/pm.

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqhxh6)

I have used this example to make my calendar work:

[Referred Link](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)
Can you please help me to go through it

TS:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(".OnlyDate")
      .datetimepicker({ format: "L", useCurrent: false })
      .on("dp.change", e => {
        if (e.date) {
          const date = e.date.format("L");
          this.date = date;
        } else {
          this.date = null;
        }
      });
    if (!this.eoList) {
      $(".effectiveDate")
        .datetimepicker({ format: "L", useCurrent: false })
        .on("dp.change", e => {
          if (e.date) {
            const date = e.date.format("L");
            this.date = date;
          } else {
            this.date = null;
          }
        });
      $(".expirationDate").datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
        format: "L",
      });
      $(".effectiveDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('.expirationDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
      });
      $(".effectiveDate").on("dp.change", e => {
        const date = e.date.format("L");
        this.date = date;
        $(".expirationDate")
          .data("DateTimePicker")
          .minDate(e.date);
      });
      $(".expirationDate").on("dp.change", e => {
        if (e.date) {
          const date = e.date.format("L");
          this.date = date;
        } else {
          this.date = null;
        }
        $(".effectiveDate").data("DateTimePicker");
      });
    } else {
      $(".effectiveDate")
        .datetimepicker({ format: "L", useCurrent: false })
        .on("dp.change", e => {
          if (e.date) {
            const date = e.date.format("L");
            this.date = date;
          } else {
            this.date = null;
          }
        });
      $(".expirationDate").datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
        format: "L",
        minDate: new Date(this.eoInfoForm.value.effectiveDate) 
      });
      $(".effectiveDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('.expirationDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
      });
      $(".effectiveDate").on("dp.change", e => {
        const date = e.date.format("L");
        this.date = date; 
         this.eoInfoForm.get('effectiveDate').setValue(this.date, { emitEvent: false });
      if (this.eoInfoForm.value.effectiveDate) {
        this.eoInfoForm.get('expirationDate').enable();
        var aYearFromNow = new Date(this.eoInfoForm.value.effectiveDate);
        aYearFromNow.setFullYear(aYearFromNow.getFullYear() + 1);
        this.eoInfoForm.get('expirationDate').patchValue(new DatePipe('en').transform(aYearFromNow, 'MM/dd/yyyy'))
      } else {
        this.eoInfoForm.get('expirationDate').disable();
      }

        $(".expirationDate")
          .data("DateTimePicker")
          .minDate(e.date);
      });
      $(".expirationDate").on("dp.change", e => {
        if (e.date) {
          const date = e.date.format("L");
          this.date = date;
           this.eoInfoForm.get('expirationDate').setValue(this.date, { emitEvent: false });
        } else {
          this.date = null;
        }
        $(".effectiveDate").data("DateTimePicker");
      });

    }

  }


}
```

Comment: That is probably specific to the control you are wanting to use and *not* angular.  Date pickers can be very difficult to get working correctly especially across browsers. You are not only dealing with the format of the date across cultures / locales you are also having to deal with time zones. Personally I would recommend you use the [material datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) which is fully integrated into angular and does not require jquery.

Comment: Also your demo does not work, there are multiple errors in the console, and your question is incomplete as you never specify the exact package you are trying to incorporate in your code. It also does not specify exactly what the problem is that you are encountering. But to reiterate my point from before I would use a well tested picker like the material datepicker.

Comment: Thanks for the response, as I have used jquery we need to do some change like give space and save in demo. My problem here is it allows me to type 13132013 which is invalid date, but the date shows to be taken as some date of correct format but while saving I get the value as 13132013 and not the date taken by calendar

Comment: And I’m not allowed to use other datepickers except this jquery one as I am using bootsrap4 mentioned in requirement

Comment: No where do you mention what the library is you are using for the datepicker and your demo link also does not contain a package. There are many different ones out there (in the 100's I am sure if you start searching github and npmjs). This is essential information you need to include with your question. *Include a full link to the library*. Also include a full [mcve] that illustrates *exactly* what is not working.

Comment: Again trying to wrap a jquery date picker in an angular control is possible but it is not easy especially when dealing with various allowed formats and time zones. I do not recommend it.

Comment: ya i will mention the package used with example.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question and making it more clear